# join two vectors with the = in R

Tags: r, vector

I want to join two vectors with the = symbol, so that the result will be: "a"="z","b"="y","c"="x"

```
a<-c("a","b","c")
b<-c("z","y","x")
c<-rbind(a,b)
```

Comment: are you looking for `setNames(b, a)`?

Comment: Or the literal `paste(a, b, sep = "=")`, though your use of `rbind` suggests you want it to *appear* like R prints a named vector on the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your desired output is as follows

```r
c("a"="z","b"="y","c"="x")
#>   a   b   c 
#> "z" "y" "x"
```

this can be achieved using `setNames` with vectors `a` and `b`

```r
a<-c("a","b","c")
b<-c("z","y","x")

setNames(b, a)
#>   a   b   c 
#> "z" "y" "x"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use `names<-` i.e

```
names(b) <- a
b

# a   b   c 
#"z" "y" "x"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a<-c("a","b","c")
b<-c("z","y","x")

c <- paste0(a, "=", b)
c

[1] "a=z" "b=y" "c=x"
```

Comment: i wish "a"="z", the = symbol without parentheses